# How do I notify Google of a change of address from http to https?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, https

I've just switched a site from http only to https only (on the same domain name), and have 301 redirects from old to new in place on a page by page basis. How do I now inform Google, using Webmaster Tools or otherwise, of this change of address so as to maintain rank?

Comment: Change of address from http to https doesnt currenlt work in webmaster tools. Use 301 and canonicals as normal.